# varsfromjobname isn't working in a test

Tags: etoolbox, jobname

I am trying to give a command depending on some information in the filename. So I use `gettwofromjobname` in a `etoolbox`-test in a file named test-a.tex, but it isn't giving me the true. Any idea why? Should I use a different test command?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varsfromjobname}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\gettwofromjobname \\
\ifdefstring{\gettwofromjobname}{a}{true}{false}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\gettwofromjobname` is not a simple macro that expands directly to the second part of the job name. Instead it contains expandable code to extract the second part of the job name. The following example defines the macro `\TwoFromJobName` to contain the second part of the job name by expanding `\gettwofromjobname`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varsfromjobname}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\gettwofromjobname \\
\edef\TwoFromJobName{\gettwofromjobname}
\ifdefstring{\TwoFromJobName}{a}{true}{false}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]